# Load data from the Database

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, sqflite

I followed the chat development app tutorial on the Flutter page, it's a single user app. I have now been able to create a database and store data in the database, but I now have a conundrum that I'm unable to resolve.

I'm loading the chats from the database using FutureBuilder

```
FutureBuilder(
                future: _requestSqlDataAsync(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data == null) {
                    return Container(
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text("Loading...."),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  else {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return Text(snapshot.data[index].chat);
                        }
                    );
```

It successfully loads the data from the database but then I'm unable to pass submit new chats from TextController to the display widget in the following manner:

```
 ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      reverse: true,
                      itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _message[index],
                      itemCount: _message.length,
)
```

where _message is the widget that combines the data from the TextController along with animation, to display the chat.

Could anyone please guide me as to how I can load the data from the database and then pass the control for the chats to be loaded.

Comment: Do you have a link for the chat tutorial?

Comment: Here you go: [Chat App](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/#10)